# How does robot framework support login to any arbitrary site

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, rpa

I am reading about robot framework:

https://blog.testproject.io/2016/11/22/robot-framework-introduction/

I have a basic question about robotframework. It uses libraries to increase its functionalities and have very simple keywords like:

[image]

How can any library support login to any random page, because the locator/id etc of submit button can be anything depending on the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "How can any library support login to any random page..."

It doesn't, and in fact the framework comes out of the box with 0 supported such logins.
You use it to create a login to *a specific site*, providing all locators and site's peculiarities yourself.

If you need it to login to another one, you create a new keyword. But it doesn't advertise it supports login to any random page, with no involvement from you :) It just provides you the means to do that, yourself.